# Robocopy in VBA while using strings

Tags: vba, robocopy

I have a spreadsheet that we run to copy over a list of files/folders based on what we select. In each of these row's we have a few other formula's that with gather other information. What we are trying to do is use robocopy based on a cell's data using strings. Below is currently how we have it setup in VBA, but it does not seem to work.

```
sSource = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value
sFile = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F2").Value
sPath = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C2").Value

Shell "cmd /c robocopy sSource sPath sFile"
```

sSource is a network drive with the full folder path (i.e. \server1\stuff\stuff2\files)
sPath is a local folder on the computer
sFile is just as it sounds, the file name

It appears that it runs successfully, but when I go to the sPath location, there are no files there, just an empty folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is very close.  You need to concatenate your variables.  All that needs to change is the final line to be:

`Shell "cmd /c robocopy " & sSource & " " & sPath & " " & sFile`

Answer (score 1):

```
strParms = " /s /xo /mir /zb /R:5 /W:5"

Shell "cmd /c robocopy " & sSource & " " & sPath & sFile & strParms
```

Replace your code line (Shell "cmd /c robocopy " & sSource & " " & sPath & " " & sFile) with above 2 lines and you'll find files in your destination folder

Actually you're missing "strParms" in your statement which I have added. I have tested and it will definitely work.